# ajax call on form completion

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form that a user completes.  after the user is done he clicks submit, the script runs and does some fancy things and returns to finished.php.  on this page I have the results of his $_POST from the form....on this new page load, I need to fire an ajax call to get the data based on his $_POST result..

in layman's code:

```
$_POST['someValue'] = "12345";

$(document).on("pageinit","users/userInfo.php",function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data:"someValue="+$_POST['someValue'],
        success: function(msg){
            $('#mainBody').html(msg);
        }
    });
});

<div id='mainBody'> --Print results of ajax call---</div>
```

how would i go about this

edited new code:

```
<script>
    $(document).on("pageinit",function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "users/userInfo.php",
            dataType: "html",
            data:"someValue=+<?php echo $_POST['someValue'];?>",
            success: function(msg){
                alert('hi');
                $('#mainBody').html(msg);
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('failure');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: nothing happens....i stare at a blank page.  how do i get the $_POST['someValue'] into the ajax function?  i tried var val=<?php echo $_POST['someValue'];?>;  but that didnt seem to help.

Comment: Maybe you can do something like `echo "<input hidden data-id=\"$_POST[someValue]\">` and then use `"someValue=" + $("[data-id]").data('id')`

Comment: What does your JavaScript console say? `data:"someValue="+$_POST['someValue'],` is obviously not what you have verbatim in your code but it still looks like you are mixing PHP and javascript without wrapping the PHP in PHP tags

Comment: i didnt think it was acceptable to insert php code in the ajax call.  the answer below by patrick is what i was thinking of trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $(document).on("pageinit",function(){
```

did not work.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
```

did.

Answer (score 1):

Your

`data:"someValue="+$_POST['someValue'],`

Should be

`data:"someValue="+<?php echo $_POST['someValue'];?>,`,

or

`data:"someValue=<?php echo $_POST['someValue'];?>",`  if the `$_POST['someValue']` is a string as it will make the javscript error out if you dont put it in quotes.

Comment: so i removed all the code inside the ajax success and just put alert('hi');    on page reload,  i did not get my alert.  seems like the call isn't successfully firing....   i get nothing in either console, or firebug.

Comment: well you need to set a url for the ajax to call. something like `$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.example.com/somescript.php",`

Comment: and what is your script returning json,html,xml? set the `dataType` as well, dataType:"json", dataType:"html" etc. and point your browser to the same address that the ajax tries to call and make sure its outputting the data in the correct format.

Comment: edited above code with new script and get same results.  pointing browser to the ajax page target gives me what i would expect.

Comment: you have `data:"someValue=+<?php echo $_POST['someValue'];?>",` , remove the + sign, you dont need it there and try again. does your alert in the `error` callback get called?

Comment: i figured it out..   see answer.